# Synchronized Realm - Airplane Mode

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Can't find anything in the documentation about falling back to the locally cached version of a synchronized realm when eg. the App is started in airplane mode. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If the user did log in before (when the connection was available) you can use `SyncUser.all()` to get a valid authenticated user, but if no user exists a network call to the auth server is required.

We are working on adding support for creating a Realm and a User without initial network connection here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

This is now open as a feature request with the Realm guys.

https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Realm was [sold to MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/press/mongodb-strengthens-mobile-offerings-with-acquisition-of-realm) in April 2019 at which point this issue was **still** outstanding. I would expect such to be tackled as part of integration of Realm's local store into a MongoDB cloud but never to be fixed in the core Realm Platform sync product.