# How deactivate synchronization for my Realm database in ios project?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have iOS application with Realm mobile database. We've integrated Realm real-time synchronisation, and need to put into the app a switch for turning off synchronisation.

App should correctly work in offline mode. How we can do this? How can we create Realm without RLMSyncUser?

Comment: I think you have to update your xcode project and release an update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942208/synchronized-realm-airplane-mode

Answer (score 2):

Realm files that are synchronized, and ones that are not are structured somewhat differently (Synchronized ones for example store more of the transaction history). As a result, it's not possible to convert a Realm file between being synchronized, and not.

At the moment, best practice for that sort of scenario would be to have a master local Realm file, on which the Realm bases its operations (even when offline), but to then have an auxiliary synchronized Realm which data can be copied to.

If you have any suggestions about how you think this feature should work, feel free to file an issue on the [Realm Mobile Platform feedback repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues)!

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: @EgorAfanasenko Please accept the answer if it is satisfactory.